# What are the commentaries available on LalitA SahasranAma?

Tags: agamas, book-recommendation, lalita

One of the most popular hymns of the goddess is Sri Lalita Sahasranama.

What are the major commentaries available on it? (apart from the Saubhagya Bhaskara by Sri Bhaskara raya)